# Variable is always empty regardless of the loop technique I use

Tags: bash, docker, for

I have a file called `dependencies` and its content is:

```
blog
forms
geo
ticketing
```

And I have this `build.sh` script in which I need to loop over them. This build script would be run inside a docker container and I have tested many ways to loop over lines of this file:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r dep || [ -n "$dep" ]
do
    echo $dep # empty
done < /path_to_dependencies
```

or

```
$( cat /path_to_dependencies ) |
while read dep;
do
    echo $dep # empty
done
```

or

```
for dep in `cat /path_to_dependencies`
do
    echo $dep # empty
done
```

or

```
while read dep;
do
   echo $dep # empty
done <<< "$( cat /path_to_dependencies )"
```

What can be the cause of this issue? I can loop over file content in my own ubuntu and there is no problem.

Comment: that first one looks right to me; the second doesn't make sense since it'd run the contents of the file as a command (probably would give errors); the third would not give lines but individual words (after globbing for filenames); and the fourth is just a silly way of doing the input redirection. If the file is there, you should be getting some output. And if it isn't, an error. Without further details, it doesn't seem simple to say much more.

Comment: It may be related to how you are building your docker image. Are you copying correctly the dependencies file into the image? What is your base image OS? Can you share your Dockerfile sample?

Comment: Do you mean you get no output, or one empty line for each line of dependencies. Have you tried running your script with `bash -o xtrace`? Also note: [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) and [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)

Comment: I'm assuming the path to the file is incorrect when you run the code in the Docker container. You do not show the file layout of the container or anything else that shows that you're using the correct path to the input file.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code example worked for me.  When I have code that **should** work but doesn't, I start from the simplest form:

```
while read dep
do
    echo "$dep"
done < ./dependencies
```

(the `dependencies` file started in the same directory, for convenience)
I added the extras around the `read` until I had your example:

```
while IFS= read -r dep || [ -n "$dep" ]
do
    echo "$dep"
done < ./dependencies
```

Both the simplified and this version gave me the output:

```
blog
forms
geo
ticketing
```

So I suggest reducing the code to the simplest form, and type in the additional parts, one at a time, until you reach the part that makes it stop working, then you can focus on it.

Comment: I believe the test for *non*-empty (note: the question used `-n` instead of the -`z` you used) input is to handle cases where the file doesn't have a final newline. In such cases `read` will return a failure status, but the variable is still filled with whatever content could be read.

Comment: The `read sep` is much much more complex than the `IFS= read -r dep` form as it does backslash escaping and complex processing involving the `$IFS` variable. Using `read sep` here would make little sense unless you happen to want to strip IFS whitespace characters from the start and end of lines and backslash is used in the dependencies file to escape field and line delimiters

Comment: Thank you muru and Stephane, I misunderstood the meaning of the `|| [ -n "$dep ]` part of the original question, and I'm removing the latter part of my answer about it.